# Use php code in setInterval Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the time from the server and update it every second. I used the setinterval function but it work only one time.

```
var gettime = function(){
var newDate= new Date("<?= date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>"); 
var seconds=newDategetSeconds();
$("#sec").html(seconds);
}
setInterval(gettime,1000);
```

and to show it

```
<div id="sec"><div>
```

but this works the time is updated every second if i use the javascript code `var newDate= new Date()` instead of the php code but gives the client time

```
var newDate= new Date("<?= date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>")
```

Comment: You'd need to either make an AJAX call to your server for the time, or reload the entire page every second

Comment: Why do you need to fetch the server time every second? You can start with the server's timestamp, but then you can let the browser count the seconds from there.

Comment: thanks @j08691, how to make the ajax call every second?

Comment: @deceze do you have an example ?